# How to rotate bezier curve? (Geometry Nodes 3.x)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to rotate geometry (bezier segment) about the point (0,.5,0).
What happens with handles?[image]
(Blender 3.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use transform?

[image]

If you want to do it manually, you should know several things.

First, you should know that than you move Beizer points, handles moves with them keeping its relative position.

[image]

So to make it work, you should at first rotate Beizer handles around its points:

[image]

Second, that you should know, is that you move one handle and handle type is not free, second handle will move accordingly. So you have to move only one handle.

Final setup:

[image]

Comment: @StoatPaws I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank You very much. Everything is clear for me now.