# Mathematically, what's happening under the hood with Shape Keys?

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals, geometry, shape-keys, mathematics

I recently put together [a node tree in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269359/2952) that emulates the functionality of Shape Keys.

The result is very close but not always exactly the same as when using native Shape Keys.

A comparison of the Geometry Nodes Shape Keys result (grey) against the native Shape Keys deformation (blue):

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with how face normals are being calculated.

So I would like to know, what is the formula Blender uses to calculate a Shape Key mix?

The goal is to "code" that math into the note setup to improve the accuracy. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the standard shape key transformation is linear, so for each vertex an offset vector is stored which is added to the original vertex location, multiplied by a factor which is given through the shape key value. If you have a second shape key, they are both added to the original location as much as their individual factor is set to. Since this is a linear transformation, things like rotating shapes cannot simply done by animating shape key values from 0 to 1.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for your comment. I am aware that rotation is not possible, as it is only handling vertex positions. In [my node setup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269359/2952) since the vertex positions must be taken from two separate objects with matching topology, the basis is subtracted from the key to get the difference, and then that is factored and added to the mix. Seems essentially the same as the process you describe. Maybe it's due to a floating point limitation during the vector addition process... and maybe that doesn't happen when Blender calculates internally.

Comment: It's a bit complicated.  You can follow the code starting in [`MOD_shapekey.c`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_shapekey.c) but given the math involved I would speculate that your guess about floating point limitations holds, even in the simple case.