# How to average or transfer between 3 meshes in Blender. Geo Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I followed a post, I created a geo node set-up were could transfer betweem 2 shapes, but that set-up also transfered the position of the object.
I want something like shape keys using the same mesh indices to morph btween 3 shapes creating an average of the shapes with weight paint control.

Comment: Is weight-paint the _only_ control, or is it modifiying another (perhaps time-based) blend?

Comment: Please clarify (illustrate ? )  what controls you want on the blend between 3 shapes;  what you'd like your interface to be. This will be possible, I'm sure, but only if we know what 'this' _is_.

Comment: @Robin Betts 
I was playing a node setup I put together, looking at some posts and videos. This is almost like a shape key the problem is it also keeps the location instead of blending like a shape key.
Ideally I'd want it be like a shape key because the use the same topology. But unlike a shape key you could blender between 3 shapes or create a average form the 3 shapes.

https://i.ibb.co/yFTgnqs/Blend-Face.gif

Comment: I know I can use shape Keys to blend between 2 mesh shapes but with a node I could have the option of not only blending between 3 mesh shapes but also creating a average of all 3 shapes. The weight paint would have a user to influence how much of each shape gets blender together or influences the average.
For example with a head I can average between 3 head but if I wanted I can use weight paints to make the nose of this head (geo) have a stronger influence on the average or blending for the final shape.

Comment: I found this post that does something similar. Which look like I can blend 3 shapes from testing.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269008/how-to-create-shape-keys-in-geometry-nodes-including-support-for-curve-handles

It just doesn't do an average if you're using for a head or similar. To create a average shape.