# interpolate geometry node shape keys

Tags: geometry-nodes, shape-keys, interpolation

[image: simpler approach][image: stepOne_online example]I am working with this great solution (at the end of the thread): ([How to create Shape Keys in Geometry Nodes, including support for curve handles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269008/how-to-create-shape-keys-in-geometry-nodes-including-support-for-curve-handles)) but cannot figure out a strategy to morph between 3 shape keys, with "procedural" animation, and get random mixtures between the 3 rather than a linear morph from 1 to 2 to 3. Thank you for ANY suggestions.

Comment: To which of the solutions shown there does your question refer? How do you animate these nodes? Which part of it is "procedural"? Maybe it would be good if you share your blend file with us: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @quellenform I was thinking about a path through RGB noise to get random but continuous mixes on 3 axes, using your groups .. it's your original answer though.. if by any chance you were thinking roughly the same.. I'll leave the answer to your more elegant style :)

Comment: this is a screenshot, a highly modified use of your example plus added node to convert curve to volume..i also tried converting the shape key curves to volumes and mixing between the meshes via 'sample index" and position nodes. I obviously don't have the needed skills.Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @RobinBetts My "elegant style" can be easily surpassed by your professional style! Besides, I currently lack the ambition to recreate the whole node tree ;-)